# AVAsset is not playable with local audio file

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

```
NSURL* fileURL=[_musicListViewModel fileURLWithModel:model];
NSData* assetData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
[audioPlayer play];
AVAsset*asset=[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
AVAsset* asset=[AVAsset assetWithURL:fileURL];
if (!asset.playable){
    [self playerErrorHandler];
    return;
}
```

*fileURL* is `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5A0A1FF9-F884-4CB9-9F59-BBFCB7C51A1B/Documents/music_data_path/yI3a6r`.

And *assetData* is not nil.

*audioPlayer* can play from the file while both *asset* initialization cannot make itself playable.

**WRONG: SUFFIX is ESSENTIAL**

Suffix of audio file is .mp3, but it doesn't work when I append suffix to file path.

What's wrong with my code???

Comment: You need to post real code that actually compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I find that suffix is essential in filePath, or AVAsset will not playable, which doesn't like AVAudioPlayer.